# Does anyone know of a good site for beginning in YUI?

Tags: php, javascript, yui

Does anyone know of a good site for beginning in YUI?

The developer's manual on Yahoo is too confusing for me.

Answer (score 2):

[Webmonkey](http://www.webmonkey.com/) has a nice little [tutorial](http://www.webmonkey.com/tutorial/Create_Rich_Interfaces_With_the_YUI_Library) about YUI.

Answer (score 2):

Try
http://www.insideria.com/2008/05/writing-your-first-yui-applica.html